# Is it possible to add a column that contains data for certain row numbers?

Tags: r

I have several big data frames which would be much easier to further analyse if I could add certain numbers in an additional column called "event".

E.g. row 19 to 53 should all have the number 1 as they belong to event no. 1, row 65 to 92 the number 2 etc. So not every row gets a number, because some data will be left out for further analysis (left out data could get 0/NA if that is needed and the column has to be continuous).

Thanks in advance!

I just know how to add a column but not how to attach specific data for certain rows.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df1 %>% mutate(grp = case_when(row_number() %in% 19:53 ~ 1, row_number() %in% 65:92 ~ 2))`

Comment: Adding a column is easy: simply `data$new_columns <- x`. But your question seems to have more to do with how to obtain `x`, that is, what's the logic of the vector that has the data of events. Please, explain a little more about your data and how you want to classify it. Check this post on how to make reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: If you know the row's numbers, you could just use the `rep()` function : `data$event=c(rep(0,18),rep(1,34),rep(0,12),rep(2,27)`, meaning you repeat '0' 18 times (0 being the 'no event' code), the '1' 34 times and so on and so forth

Comment: @akrun, that worked, thanks! Not sure if it's the easiest way, but I get what I want. :)

Answer (score 2):

We could use `case_when` to modify specific row index with a value

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(grp = case_when(row_number() %in% 19:53 ~ 1, 
   row_number() %in% 65:92 ~ 2))
```

---

Or using `base R` - create the column for specific index by `rep`licating the values that many times i.e. `53 - 19 = 34` and `92-65 =27`)

```
df1$grp[c(19:53, 65:92)] <- rep(c(1,2), c(34, 27))
```